# Free `mmap()-ed` Private Hugepages

Tags: c, linux, centos7, mmap, huge-pages

I have the following code:

```
mmap(NULL, 2048, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0);
```

I wonder how to free the hugepages after my application exits abnormally (e.g. crashed).

Rebooting the machine will free all the hugepages.  But this is a bit disruptive to production server.  Hence, I am looking for a way not to disrupt existing processes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's nothing left to clean up if the application has crashed already :)

Comment: @tangrs I noticed that the numa free page count is dropping tho (`numastat -vm`).

Comment: Linux will have complex memory management algorithms. I doubt the output from `numastat` will have any direct relationship with your processes crashing or starting. [Linux Ate My RAM](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) is not directly related to this but helps illustrate the point (in particular, the distinction between _free_ and _available_).

Comment: @tangrs right the counter might be wrong but when my application tries to mmap again.  Mmap complains no more resource

Comment: @HCFS Maybe, just maybe try deleting files in the hugepages mount point. This is not a solution, but a dirty hack. It worked for me, but may not work for you, specially if multiple applications are sharing tlbpages. ymmv.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer i ended up rebooting the machine which has the same effect as what you suggested.  So I am looking for a solution without rebooting nor affecting the existing processes. Thanks tho

Comment: @HCSF Sorry about that. Even the duplicate with an accepted answer seems to suggest this hack. Seemingly, tlb files are deleted when the last FD to it closes. I won't link that duplicate, because chaps here will quickly mark duplicate without properly reasoning/studying alternatives/explaining why.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer no worry.  I will update my post to clarify what I am looking for.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When the program terminates, the mappings are automatically unmapped.

Below statement is from the book "The Linux Programming Interface".

> All of a process’s mappings are automatically unmapped when it
>   terminates or performs an exec().

Comment: Textbooks can be outdated. Maybe show a reference to man pages or something that's reasonably up to date?

Comment: Manpage does say so `The region is also automatically unmapped when the process is terminated.  On the other hand, closing the file descriptor does not unmap the region.`  Tho, I know it isn't true because I have also dealt with the regular SHM in `/dev/shm` not being cleaned up for months...

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way of solving the problem but not the only way.

You're opening `mmap` with FD set to -1. Instead, try with a file like this:

```
char page_file[256];
static unsigned page_counter;
int fd;

/* page_counter must be counted up and must be unique. */
snprintf(page_file, sizeof(page_file), "/var/huge/my_page_%u", page_counter);

fd = open(page_file, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0755);
if (fd == -1) {
    /* Handle error. */
}

addr = mmap(NULL, 2048, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_HUGETLB, fd, 0);
```

Your application initialisation procedure can then look for files with the prefix `/var/huge/my_page_*` or whatever you chose for your application and delete those files before calling `mmap`. That way, you will not lose on the space.

Now for the caveats.

1. If this page is shared across by other applications and your application comes back from crash, things will be get fatal. So use this solution with care. I suggested this because you're not sharing your pages with other applications as far as I can see.
2. After you delete files, another application `mmap`s huge pages during this time before you can allocate, you won't be able to use the huge pages.

Comment: `$ ll /var/huge/` returns `ls: cannot access /var/huge/: No such file or directory`.  Probably CentOS 7 is different.  And I think `mmap()` will ignore or reject file descriptor != -1 when `MAP_PRIVATE` is specified because the region is meant to be private and content won't be written back to disk.

Comment: @HCSF It is your choice where you mount hugepages (as root). People normally mount it on `/mnt/huge` or some place. Check your `/proc/mounts` for details. I usually do so in `/var/huge`. As for `MAP_PRIVATE` I don't think it would get rejected.